# Since TypeScript 1.5 includes ES6 modules, is the ES6 module loader still required?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

The [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) demo uses Traceur and System.JS to implement ES6 module syntax. Since [Typescript 1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-15) now includes this syntax, is the separate ES6 module loader still required? Any ideas of how to do without it?

```
<head>
  <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
  <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<my-app></my-app>
<script>System.import('app');</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you transpile ES6+ code that uses ES6 modules to ES5, you have to decide for a module system that works in ES5. That can be CommonJS, AMD, SystemJS, UMD.

Even if TypeScript is going to be a superset of ES6 and implement ES6 modules, as soon as you transpile your code, you need to use a module system that the browser understands today.

Unfortunately, there's no spec that defines *how* modules are loaded anymore. So yes, you'd still need to use something like SystemJS to load modules in ES5.

Comment: The problem is I use browserify for everything and there seems to be no way to use browserify with angular2. Was hoping I didn't need system.js.

Comment: Oh, well browserify uses CommonJS syntax, so you could transpile A2 with CommonJS modules and it should work :)